# Additional action on successful ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a modal with a form. On a button click withing the modal I send couple values to another php file that has a script to add the values to my db.

I need to do some modal manipulation after the values are stored. I've tried this but it does not seem to be working, even thos I get no errors and the values are stored in my db OK...

```
$(document).on('click', '.addNumber', function() {
    var newNum = $('input#newNumber').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/addNewPhoneNumber.ajax',
        data: {
            'bid' : bid,
            'nbr' : newNum
        },
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).addClass('none');
        $('#newNumber').remove();
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) in done function is not the button you need to something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.addNumber', function() {
    var newNum = $('input#newNumber').val();
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/addNewPhoneNumber.ajax',
        data: {
            'bid' : bid,
            'nbr' : newNum
        },
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function() {
        that.addClass('none');
        $('#newNumber').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`(this)` is not working inside `ajax request` because it is overwritten by `ajax`.
So assign `object` this to new variable before `ajax request` and then use that variable instead of `$(this)`